# Import forms.form to template

Tags: django, django-templates

New to Django so sorry if this is trivial

I have a "base.html" template that is extended by a lot of other templates.  In this "base.html" template I have a form that is generated from a "forms.Form" derived class called "SearchForm"
. 
The question is: Can I import "SearchForm" into the the "base.html" template instead of passing the "Searchform" as a context to every view that is derived from "base.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use Django's template context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext).

Here's a simple example:

```
def search_form_context_processor(request):
    return {'form': SearchForm() }
```

Then update your `settings.py` with

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ....
    my_module.search_form_context_processor,
    ....
)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors

After this, `{{ form }}` will be available on any templates which you render using `render_to_response` with a `RequestContext` passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Like Issac Kelly wrote you can create a templatetag which will add form to your context. The docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/).

To add form to your context you can write

```
class FormNode(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        context['form'] = MyForm()
        return ''

def add_form_to_context(parser, token):
    return FormNode()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other options (besides @Derek's) are to have a custom template tag that either A) writes the form html, or B) adds the form to the page context.